# Connect with PayPal button

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I try to get user paypal account info through  Connect with PayPal button .Every thing is working fine .User is authenticated and redirected to REDIRECTURI which is a success route .I get a code on success route in query param.But how i would get the user profile with the code in query param ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to complete additional steps of a [Connect with PayPal integration](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/integrate/#5-get-authorization-code), namely:

(6.) Get access token, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/connect-with-paypal/integrate/#sample-request

(8.) Show user profile information, https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/identity/v1/#userinfo_get

Comment: In Paypal docs only first step is described with code.All other steps and their end points are present in an Image provided in docs.

Comment: There is a sample request in Step 6, which I linked to.  Step 8 links to the `userinfo` API method.